# Booting a Microblaze (on OVPsim)

Tags: assembly, simulation, gnu-assembler, microblaze

I want to write some code that will boot a simulated (on OVPsim) Microblaze processor.

I have built a platform that is truly bare metal - ie no semihosting library. But I am unfamiliar with writing .S files, as opposed to some small bits of inline assembly.

So, I want to specify that my assembler .text section is located at physical address 0x00000000

In the Linux kernel head.S file, the boot code is preceded by two macros:

```
__HEAD
```

and

```
ENTRY(_start)
```

From what I can see by grepping the sources neither is Microblaze specific:

```
__HEAD
```

appears to expand to:

```
 .section        ".head.text","ax"
```

and I cannot really see what

```
ENTRY(_start)
```

expands to, but it looks like nothing much (??)

Anybody able to explain to me what I need to preface my bootup .text with?

Answer (score 1):

You should start with learning `crt0.s` (as well as other `crt*.s` files) from Xilinx. These files initialize C run-time environment for standalone, non-Linux program, running on MicroBlaze.

Basically those startup files do bare minimum:

- provide addresses for MicroBlaze reset, interrupt, exception vectors, initializes;
- initialize stack and other Xilinx ABI registers (`.bss`, `.sbss`, `.rodata`);
- initialize `.bss` section with zeros;
- call your `main()` function.

For Xilinx 14.3 their location is `Xilinx/14.3/ISE_DS/EDK/sw/lib/microblaze/src/`. Or just search for `crt0.s` over your Xilinx folder or google it.